# ESLint disable max-len rule for define()

Tags: requirejs, eslint

I am using requirejs and I have some files which have a define statement which exceeds the max-len rule in my eslint config.

The rule is set to 180, I don't really want to increase this just to avoid problems on the define line.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there a way to ignore define lines in the eslint config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.

In the eslint config, in the max-len rule I added the ignorePattern option and ignored lines starting with define.

Would be interested if anyone has an alternative solution.